# How to manage logged in session in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, session, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a login controller which autheticates userId and password and set the userId in session , now by legacy I can allways check for the userId key in session ..if present user is logged in if not then usr is not authenticated for the particular request.

Now the problem with this approch is I every time have to explicitly check for the userId field in session in some controller (in fact in each function within the controller) with restricted login and in some I need not to check ..as the pages are meant to have public access.

What are the better ways to handle the loggedin/loggged out situation?? Is there any spring specific approch??

Comment: Use servlet `Filter`s or spring `Interceptor`s. You would have to specify when you should be logged in and when not.

Comment: thought of that ...but how do I know which pages are at public and which are at private ... at that level I have hundreads of url request to handle ...and their is no prefix to bifercate between different url types

Comment: You have to define a some way. If you're pressed for time, maybe compile a list of uri (or uri patterns) that should be matched which you give to your filter/interceptor. If one is matched for a request, check logged in (redirect if not logged in), otherwise let it through. If you have plenty of time and want to learn something new, Spring Security or Shiro will be more effective in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring Security http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html

It does most of your requirements out of the box for free.